# Google Speech API Won't Accept Large Audio Files

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm receiving a server error when trying to process large audio files. The audio files are originally audio/m4a @ 32kHz and per the recommendations of the documentation am converting/compressing them to audio/amr_wb @ 16kHz. These files are well below the 180 minutes of audio limit yet I'm still receiving a server error when processing them.

`GaxError Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by 8:Received message larger than max (5371623 vs. 4194304)`

I'm using version `V1p1beta` and the method `long_running_recognize` to transcribe these audio files. My files are hosted on Google Cloud Storage and I'm providing the uri in my api call.

How can I send large audio files to the API without the server enforcing a size restriction ? It seems wrong to recommend using FLAC or WAV and having a 180 minutes of length in audio limit if the server can't even handle my hour long audio file that has been encoded to AMR_WB.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Currently Speech-to-Text API released the [v1 endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize), I suggest trying this version. I was able to get a proper response by using a 90 minute audio.